# text not appear in release mode flutter andriod

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I run my app in debug mode , it works fine but when generate apk the text not show, this some images in debug and release.

**Debug Mode:**

[image: debug mode image 1]

**Release Mode:**

[image: release mode image 1]

> ```
> [environment:
>   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
>
> dependencies:
>   flutter:
>     sdk: flutter
>   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
>   flutter_localizations:
>     sdk: flutter
>   sizer: ^1.1.8
>   gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.3
>   http: ^0.13.4
>   rflutter_alert: ^1.1.0
>   loading_overlay: ^0.2.1
>   shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
>   anim_search_bar: ^1.0.1
>   geolocator: ^7.6.2
>   flutter_polyline_points: ^0.2.4
>   google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
>   maps_launcher: ^2.0.1
>   new_gradient_app_bar: ^0.1.5
>   multi_select_flutter: ^3.1.8
>   image_picker: ^0.8.4+8
>   printing: ^5.7.2
>   pdf: ^3.7.1
>   flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
>   connectivity_plus: ^2.2.1]
> ```
>
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1713
> darwin-x64, locale en-SA)
> • Flutter version 2.10.1 at /Users/raitotec/developer/flutter
> • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
> • Framework revision db747aa133 (4 weeks ago), 2022-02-09 13:57:35 -0600
> • Engine revision ab46186b24
> • Dart version 2.16.1
> • DevTools version 2.9.2
>
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
> version 30.0.2)
> • Android SDK at /Users/raitotec/Library/Android/sdk
> • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
> • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
> • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> ! Flutter recommends a minimum Xcode version of 13.
> Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
> • CocoaPods version 1.11.2
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin version 51.0.1
> • Dart plugin version 193.7547
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
>
> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
> • iPhone 12 mini (mobile) • A9648508-3B05-4468-B593-477288FC7370 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4
> (simulator)
>
> [✓] HTTP Host Availability
> • All required HTTP hosts are available

this my page code

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:delegate_app/Api/LoginApi.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/Constans/Style.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/Localization/language.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/Localization/language_constants.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/Routes/route_constants.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/Shared_View/AppBarView.dart';
import 'package:delegate_app/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:loading_overlay/loading_overlay.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

class startPage extends StatefulWidget {
  startPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _startPageState createState() => _startPageState();
}

class _startPageState extends State<startPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SafeArea(child: Scaffold(
      //resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      //  appBar: AppBarWithBack(context, ''),
        body: LoadingOverlay(
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: Style.BoxDecoration1,
                child: FormUI(),
              ),

          isLoading: _isLoading,
          opacity: 0.2,
          color: Style.MainColor,
          progressIndicator: CircularProgressIndicator(valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Style.MainColor),))
        ));
  }

  Widget FormUI() {
    return Center(child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( vertical: 15.0),),
     //   Image(image: AssetImage('lib/assets/logo.png'), width: 50.0.w),
        Container(
          decoration: Style.BoxDecorationWithRadiusOny,

          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 35.0 ,vertical: 30.0),
          child:  Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child:Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric( horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 20.0),
              child:Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Password
                  Theme(
                    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(primaryColor: Style.SecondryColor ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                    //  obscureText: true,
                      controller: nameController,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value.isEmpty) {
                        return getTranslated(context,'CompanyNumber_Validation');
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    cursorColor: Style.SecondryColor,
                     style: Style.MainText14,
                    decoration:  InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home_work_outlined),
                      hintText: '',
                      labelText: getTranslated(context, 'CompanyNumber'),
                      labelStyle: Style.GreyText14,
                      hintStyle: Style.GreyText14,
                        errorStyle: Style.GreyText14.copyWith(color: Colors.red)
                    ),
                        onEditingComplete: () {
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      }
                  ),
                  ),
                  // Login Button
                  Padding(
                    padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 2.0.h, 0, 0),
                    child:  Container(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 1.0.h, 0, 1.0.h),
                      decoration: Style.BoxDecorationWithRadius,
                      child: FlatButton(
                        child: Text(
                          getTranslated(context, 'login_btn'),
                          style: Style.Header5,

                        ),
                        onPressed: ()async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                           showLoading();
                           var res= await StartToLogin(context,nameController.text);
                           hideLoading();
                           if(res != null)
                           {
                             Navigator.pushNamed(context, loginRoute);
                           }


                        }},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),),
        ),
      ],
    ),
      );

  }

  void showLoading() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading=true;
    });
  }

  void hideLoading() {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading=false;
    });
  }

}
```

this code of getTranslated

```
String getTranslated(BuildContext context, String key) {
  return DemoLocalization.of(context).translate(key);
}
```

> ```
> import 'dart:convert';
> import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
> import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
>
> class DemoLocalization {
>   DemoLocalization(this.locale);
>
>   final Locale locale;
>   static DemoLocalization of(BuildContext context) {
>     return Localizations.of<DemoLocalization>(context, DemoLocalization);
>   }
>
>   Map<String, String> _localizedValues;
>
>   Future<void> load() async {
>     String jsonStringValues =
>         await rootBundle.loadString('lib/lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
>     Map<String, dynamic> mappedJson = json.decode(jsonStringValues);
>     _localizedValues =
>         mappedJson.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
>   }
>
>   String translate(String key) {
>     return _localizedValues[key];
>   }
>
>   // static member to have simple access to the delegate from Material App
>   static const LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> delegate =
>       _DemoLocalizationsDelegate();
> }
>
> class _DemoLocalizationsDelegate
>     extends LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> {
>   const _DemoLocalizationsDelegate();
>
>   @override
>   bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
>     return ['en', 'ar',].contains(locale.languageCode);
>   }
>
>   @override
>   Future<DemoLocalization> load(Locale locale) async {
>     DemoLocalization localization = new DemoLocalization(locale);
>     await localization.load();
>     return localization;
>   }
>
>   @override
>   bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<DemoLocalization> old) => false;
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you share us getTranslated function?

Comment: @YasinEge
String getTranslated(BuildContext context, String key) {
  return DemoLocalization.of(context).translate(key);
}

Answer (score 0):

Problem is from the package 'Sizer' it returns ZERO when you use .sp on Texts,
make sure that you have your Material app Wrapped directly with Sizer inside build function

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp(); });
}
```

if that doesn't work for you, you can override fontSize for Text widgets styles like:

```
Text(
      getTranslated(context, 'login_btn'),
      style: Style.Header5?.copyWith(fontSize: 14.sp),
    )
```